# How do I replace the dump of my USB recovery media with a more simple EFI partition in this situation?

Tags: boot, windows-8.1, uefi, efi, linux-kvm

The situation is as follows:

- this is a new Dell Precision M3800;
- it comes with a Windows 8.1 pro version and a USB recovery medium;
- the machine uses UEFI;
- I immediately scratched Windows and installed Ubuntu 15.04 on it;
- and my Windows version now runs in a VM.

The VM is as follows:

- it is a qemu x86_64 VM (virt-manager shows the emulator as being `/usr/bin/kvm-spice`);
- legacy firmware, not UEFI;
- there are two disks: the second is a dump (using `dd`) of the USB recovery medium, the first is the disk where the Windows install actually resides.

But as I went a little too fast, I botched the install somewhat and the disk where Windows resides is not bootable; I have to keep the dump of the USB recovery medium...

There are a lot of documentations on the net about EFI, GPT, etc but I have failed so far to find a guide telling me how to go about creating a simple "EFI disk" to replace that USB dump. If that helps, I do have another external USB medium which boots Ubuntu, so I can probably use that, I just don't know how...

So, is it possible to replace that USB dump with a more simple, "bare bones" EFI disk image? If yes, how to proceed?

Comment: if you just want a UEFI bootable windows installation disk, format the USB to FAT32 then copy all contents from Windows 8.1 ISO to it.

Comment: @Chris.C this is what I already have in fact (by having `dd`ed the raw USB device to a file); what I'd like is a minimal EFI boot manager instead of the full dump

Comment: the UEFI bios is capable of selecting and booting multiple EFI systems which kinda serve the purpose of traditional boot manager, or maybe sth. like this? http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/

Comment: @Chris.C uh, I am not familiar with (U)EFI; it looks like it would be able to fit my needs, but then what about OVMF as a firmware? Really, I have a lot of trouble understanding all of this :/